# Passing a pointer to an array of structs to a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm having trouble interpreting this sentence into code:
A function called max_occurences() that has ***a pointer to an array of struct occurrences*** as an argument.

My understanding is that they mean something like this:

```
int max_occurences(struct occurrence *occurrences[])
```

But this appears to be wrong. Can someone help me understand what it's suppose to look like? I'm really confused.

Comment: Thats an array of pointers to structs (2 level of indirection). You should just lose either the `*` or the `[]`. You may also want to pass a length value to indicate how many items are in your array. Unless of course its terminated with some sort of [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Answer (score 1):

```
int max_occurences(struct occurrence *occurrences[])
```

The argument here is array of pointers to `struct occurrence`.

A pointer to an array of `struct occurrence` would be declared as -

```
struct occurrence (*occurrences)[3];
```

So your argument should be -

```
int max_occurences(struct occurrence (*occurrences)[])
```